# Lookup algorithm that returns regions?

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates, quadtree

I have a large list of regions with 2D coordinates.  None of the regions overlap.  The regions are not immediately adjacent to one another and do not follow a placement pattern.

Is there an efficient lookup algorithm that can be used to let me know what region a specific point will fall into?  This seems like it would be the exact inverse of what a QuadTree is.

Comment: check this link: http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/

Comment: Why do you think that's the inverse of a QuadTree? A QuadTree is the structure that you're looking for.

Comment: What is a region? A rectangle? A polygon? If it's a polygon, do the bounding boxes overlap?

Comment: The regions are all perfect squares.  Though a friend let me know i was thinking too specifically (i was thinking i needed only 1 result from the tree).  I can use the quad tree to return me a handful of items and then iterate over them to find the exact square the point was in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data structure you need is called an R-Tree. Most RTrees permit a "Within" or "Intersection" query, which will return any geographic area containing or overlapping a given region, see, e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

There is no reason that you cannot build your own R-Tree, its just a variant on a balanced B-Tree which can hold extended structures and allows some overlap. [This implementation](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/) is lightweight, and you could use it here by wrapping your regions in rectangles. Each query might return more than one result but then you could check the underlying region. Its probably an easier solution than trying to build a polyline-supporting R-tree version.

Comment: I agree, after reading a bit about RTrees it appears it is the correct route.  The implementation was a bit more complex than a QuadTree.. and as you saw in the above comment, a friend pointed out i wasn't thinking clearly and could use a quadTree all along.  I now use a Quad and then just iterate over the handful of results it delivers until i find the exact match.

Answer (score 2):

What you need, if I understand correctly, is a [point location data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location) that is, as you put it, somehow the opposite of quad or R-tree. In a point location data structure you have a set of regions stored, and the queries are of the form: given point p give me the region in which it is contained.

Several point location data structures exists, the most famous and the one that achieves the best performance is the Kirkpatrick's one also known as triangulation refinement and achieves O(n) space and O(logn) query time; but is also famous to be hard to implement. On the other hand there are several simpler data structures that achieves O(n) or O(nlogn) space but O(log^2n) query time, which is not that bad and way easier to implement, and for some is possible to reduce the query time to O(logn) using a method called fractional cascading.

I recommend you to take a look into chapter 6 of de Berg, Overmars, et al. [Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/) which explains the subject in a way very easy to grasp, though it doesn't includes Kirkpatrick's method, which you can find it in [Preparata's book](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387961316) or read it directly from [Kirkpatrick's paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0212002?journalCode=smjcat).

BTW, several of this structures assumes that your regions are not overlapping but are expected to be adjacent (regions share edges), and the edges forms a connected graph, some times triangular regions are also assumed. In all cases you can extend your set of regions by adding new edges, but don't you worry for that, since the extra space needed will be still linear, since the final set of regions will induce a planar graph. So you can blindly extend your sets of regions without worrying with too much growth of space.

Comment: I've just read your previous comment, about having rectangular regions, if the sides are only vertical or horizontal there are other point location structures that behaves better for such kind of regions, the slab decomposition could be a nice data structure for your problem. Though, the rest are a nice reading if sometime you need something more general someday.

Comment: Also, if you are making just one query, it could be very inefficient ton construct the whole data structure, even for the quad tree then serach returned regions. Why won't you just scan all the reagions and search for the point? It could be more cheaper than building a data structure. If your regions are sorted, you can do it without a data structure in O(logn) time, the slab decomposition may give you a hint on how to do it.